Use google gemini api through proxy
I try to access gemini api through proxy but it fail with error
I try to run this code
import google.generativeai as genai
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'https://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'https://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'https://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'https://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"])

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash")
response = model.generate_content(["Hi"])
print(response.text)

but I an error ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.
What can I do to fix it
